# XPath doesn't return results from document

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, xhtml

I am trying this XPath query but it returns an empty enumeration.
Is someone familiar with this problem?
Other XPath queries on AJAX loaded XMLs work fine.
document is XHTML1.1
I am suspecting xhtml namespace (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")

Always display 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<table id="tbl">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
//ORIGINAL: var result = document.evaluate('table#tbl/tr/td[3]/text()', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var result = document.evaluate('//body', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var node;
var c = 0;
while (node = result.iterateNext()) c++;
alert(c);       // Always 0??? Why?
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `<html>` is in a namespace, the query you are running is actually running against the empty namespace.

The third parameter in `document.evaluate` refers to a `namespaceResolver` which does what it says on the tin - resolves namespaces based on their namespace prefixes [1].

Now you can either have a dynamic one or create your own, depending on whether the document you're consuming is your own or can change.

Assuming that the namespace prefix is empty (which it seems like, as it is most of the time), you want to replace that `null` with an `nsResolver` such that [3]:

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    '' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
```

Alternatively, see the dynamic example which might save you time in the long term [2].

### References

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document.createNSResolver
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver

Comment: +1 to give me the right direction. BTW if there is no prefix in XPath elements, there is no nsResolver callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete fix for XHTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<table id="tbl">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
var f = function(prefix) {alert(prefix);
  var ns = {'h' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'};
  return ns[prefix] || null;
};
var result = document.evaluate('//h:table[@id="tbl"]/h:tr/h:td[3]/text()', document, f, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var node;
while (node = result.iterateNext()) alert(node.nodeName);
</script>
</html>
```